# PowerShell - WPF DataGridView has a small additional gap between first column and the Grid

Tags: wpf, powershell, datagridview

I am building a PowerShell GUI script with WPF. The DataGrid control has two columns.

```
$dataGridView1 = New-Object Windows.controls.DataGrid 
$dataGridView1.Name = 'ListBox1'
$dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = $false
$dataGridView1.HorizontalAlignment = "Stretch"
$dataGridView1.VerticalAlignment = "Stretch"
$dataGridView1.ColumnWidth = "*"
$dataGridView1.Margin = New-Object Windows.Thickness(20, 200, 20, 20)

$dataGridView1.SelectionMode = [Windows.Controls.DataGridSelectionMode]::Single
$dataGridView1.CanUserResizeRows = $false
$dataGridView1.CanUserResizeColumns = $false

$printerNameColumn = New-Object Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn
$printerNameColumn.Header = "Printer Name"
$printerNameColumn.Binding = New-Object Windows.data.Binding("ShareName")
$dataGridView1.Columns.Add($printerNameColumn)

$printerLocationColumn = New-Object Windows.controls.DataGridTextColumn 
$printerLocationColumn.Header = "Location"
$printerLocationColumn.Binding = New-Object Windows.data.Binding("Location")
$dataGridView1.Columns.Add($printerLocationColumn)
```

[image]

I wanted to get rid of the additional space shown in the image. Is it even possible ?

I am new to PowerShell wpf frameworks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the rows headers column. If you don't use them, you can [turn off their visibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.headersvisibility?view=windowsdesktop-8.0):

C-Sharp:

```cs
dataGridView1.HeadersVisibility = DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column;
```

PowerShell:

```
$DataGrid.HeadersVisibility = "column"
```

**P.S.** Additional advice: DataGridView is a completely different element from the Win Forms platform. You should not name a DataGrid from WPF this way. This can confuse your interlocutors and complicate mutual understanding.

Comment: $dataGridView1.HeadersVisibility = DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column is throwing an error " The term 'DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet ". However Your answer was an enlightenment to think the extra space as "Rows' headers" thus I set the  " $dataGridView1.HeadersVisibility = 0" OR $datGridView1.RowHeaderWidth = 0 and it resolved my issues. 
Thanks P.S too

Comment: @SajithS.K Do you have a WPF application? And are you using the default DataGrid? If so, then such a problem should not have arisen. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridheadersvisibility?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

Comment: No WPF application & using default Data Grid. I'm building a GUI based script where user can select the location to identify the printers & install it.

Comment: @SajithS.K I took a screenshot and put it in my answer.

Comment: Is this C#? I have seen that many properties & methods are not directly available in PowerShell environment. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @SajithS.K Yes - it's Sharpe. BUT only the syntax should be different.
Perhaps this would be correct: `$dataGridView1.HeadersVisibility = [DataGridHeadersVisibility]$Column`

Comment: $dataGridView1.HeadersVisibility = [DataGridHeadersVisibility]$Column is giving unable to find type [DataGridHeadersVisibility]. A slight change like this  $DataGrid.HeadersVisibility = "column" fixed my problem too. Thank you again.

Comment: @SajithS.K I added this option of yours to my answer.
I hope you don't mind?